# PHP Hide text from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling data from an array, but show certain parts of the data above others, I've managed to choose certain text to go above others. Is there anyway to hide text from the array if it matches the piece of text I give it, using the below code?

```
<?php $datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, $leftoshownumber); // First 6 items
                foreach($datas as $data) {
                echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
            }; ?>
```

This is the full code for this section

```
            <div class="checkmark-outer">

            <?php $startnumber = 6; $parkingnumber = 0; $gardennumber = 0; $dishwashernumber = 0; $summerrentnumber = 0; ?>

            <?php if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Reduced Summer') !== false) { $summerrentnumber = 1; echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Reduced Summer Rent Available</div></div>';}; ?>
            <?php if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Parking') !== false) {$parkingnumber = 1; echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Parking Available</div></div>';}; ?>
            <?php if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Garden') !== false) {$gardennumber = 1; echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Garden</div></div>';}; ?>
            <?php if (strpos($facilitiesstring, 'Dishwasher') !== false) {$dishwashernumber = 1; echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">Dishwasher</div></div>';}; ?>

            <?php $totalfixednumber = $parkingnumber + $gardennumber + $dishwashernumber + $summerrentnumber; $leftoshownumber = $startnumber - $totalfixednumber;?>

            <?php $datas = array_slice($facilities, 0, $leftoshownumber); // First 6 items
                foreach($datas as $data) {
                echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
            }; ?>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="read-more-show hide">Show More</div><div class="read-more-content"><?php $datas = array_slice($facilities, 6); // Items after 6
                foreach($datas as $data) {
                echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
            }; ?><div class="clearfix"></div><div class="read-more-hide hide">Show Less</div></span></div>         
        </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what exactly you want as HTML output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you don't want to print the whole line, when the name matches a given variable?
Then I would do:

```
$iDontWant="bla"

foreach($datas as $data) {
            if($data->Name == $iDontWant) continue; 
            echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
        }; ?>
```

EDIT:

if you want multiple names not to show you could do:

```
$iDontWant1="bla1"
$iDontWant2="bla2"
$iDontWant3="bla3"

foreach($datas as $data) {
        if($data->Name == $iDontWant1 || $data->Name == $iDontWant2 || $data->Name == $iDontWant3) continue; 
        echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
    }; ?>
```

('||' stands for 'or' by the way)

So basically what you are doing is saying, when

**either** the name is the same as the content of `$iDontWant1`, which is "bla1"

**or** the name is the same as `$iDontWant2`, which is "bla2"

**or** the name is the same as the content of `$iDontWant3`, which is "bla3"

**do** continue (don't print this part).

**However** if you know what "bla1", "bla2" ... are, it is easier to just do

```
 foreach($datas as $data) {
        if($data->Name == "bla1" || $data->Name == "bla2" || $data->Name == "bla3") continue; 
        echo '<div class="checkmark-33"><div class="fa-stack fa-1x checkmark-icon"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i><i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x icon-text"></i></div><div class="checkmark-inner">'. $data->Name .'</div></div>'; 
    }; ?>
```

You will just compare to the String directly instead of comparing to the variable containing the string.

I hope I can help you with this.

But if you'd like to do more stuff with PHP I'd recommend a tutorial like https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php to really understand the concepts behind this language

Comment: Same goes for the second part(the show more part) obviously.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted! thanks! Would it be possible to have another $iDontWant with another word? I can't seem to get a second one to work

Comment: Edited the answer to answer that

Comment: I'm sorry if I miss judged your PHP skills, btw.